# Positioning an element on top of 2 other elements

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs and want to put a div on top of them. What CSS properties may help with this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: you can use position:absolute and set top and left css properties

Comment: Can you make and example, like on jsfiddle for instance, so we can see what you mean? Or an image?

Comment: @dude i want a image overlapping my header division and the division just below it. i wish to post the image of what i want to do but i can't post a image. so sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/L6yRZ/

```
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
```

Position absolute will position the element outside of the normal flow, relative to nearest ancestor with a position that isn't `fixed`. `top` makes the top 50px lower than the ancestor, while `left` makes the left 50px right from the left edge of the ancestor.